# Communication Between WSO2IS and Mobile Application For User Authentication

Tags: android, mobile, wso2, wso2-iot, wso2-identity-server

In my **mobile application**, I am using **wso2is**(**wso2 identity server**) for **user authentication**. But i am not getting, how my mobile application and wso2is will communicate to each other for user authentication. Can i get any specific **document/small POC or example** for communication between mobile application and wso2is ?

Answer (score 0):

it depends how the mobile application communicate, there are multiple options.

For the full backend authentication the mobile app could use e.g. [OAuth 2.0 password profile](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) . Effectively - posting the client_id, client_secret, username and password to the token endpoint and the IS server returns a JSON with an access token. With the access token the application could ask for user details.

For web authentication (it could be a full mobile app with a web component) the IS server offers

- OAuth with code or implicit grand
- OIDC
- [SAML SSO Authentication](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf)

There's even an admin API server (a SOAP web service) to validate user credentials, but I don't think it is (or should be) used in this case.